# How find xml string values and set equal to java variable?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

Is there any way to refer string values of xml fro java ?  how

can I set my xml string values located at `res/values/strings.xml` equal to a string variable

in my java class so that i can change the strings' values whenever i want at runtime.

Comment: You edit xml files programmatically. You can only fetch and manipulate the values which reside in these files.

Comment: how can i fetch and manipulate the string values ??? @user3249477

Comment: You have said what you want, but not why.  You are probably trying to do the wrong thing.  Tell us why, and we can tell you how.

Comment: because I need to change the values at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate strings or any other type of resources at runtime...at the least you can copy its values but the changes cannot be persisted or committed to the actual resource file. These are resources your application uses and should remain untouched during the lifecycle of your application.

If you want to modify and change values in your application that have some sort persistence you can read about the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) available in Android. You've got various options to choose from:

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- Sqlite Database
- and, Network Connections

Make sure you understand each option so you can make an informed decision when choosing between them. If you want to retrieve a particular string resource value, it is as simply as the snippet shown below...

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.your_string_resource_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare like this.

```
    String Str1="next";

    String str2=getResources().getString(R.string.String_id_here);
    if(Str1.equals(str2)){
        //code here
    }else{
        //code here
    }
```

Comment: no i don't want to compare, i want to change the values from my java class. @bhavesh